# Visual Studio not recognizing namespace in project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am following a training course on Pluralsight to learn .Net core. I have a folder called 'Data' which contains another folder called 'Entities' that I want to import into my views.

[image: Structure]

I want to import those classes so that I can have intellisense when editing my views.

I have a _ViewImports.cshtml file that I've been using to do this. It looks like this.

```
@using PluralsightTraining.Controllers
@using PluralsightTraining.ViewModels
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

And these namespace imports work just fine. But when trying to add

```
@using PluralsightTraining.Data.Entities
```

I get an error that says "The type or namespace 'entities' does not exist in the namespace 'PluralsightTraining.Data'.

I noticed that when I hit period after PluralsightTraining I get autocomplete to recognize the Data directory but that doesn't happen after I put a period after Data.

[image: AutoComplete]

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Look for the namespaces of the classes inside "entities". So far we've seen there is such a folder, but folder and namespaces are completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check files in Data/Entities folder,do the have their namespaces written like this?

```
 namespace PluralsightTraining.Data.Entities
{
   //Your class here
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. The course provided those three classes and I just realized the namespace didn't match the namespace of my project. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome.These things happens a lot in the learning period.